# Getting The checksum from a file by itself

Tags: bash, unix, sed, checksum

So I'm trying to get a checksum as its own thing from a file, but I'm having trouble separating it:

```
mkdir check

for FILE in *;
do


CHECKSUM=$(cksum $FILE)
CHECKSUMFIXED=CHECKSUM|sed 's/\s.*$//'

echo "$CHECKSUM"
echo "$CHECKSUMFIXED"



done
```

Checksum puts out a format of

```
<checksum> <byte size of the file> <file name>
```

but I just need the first part- but the output I get form this script is the original format

Comment: Give any input and output ?

Comment: Whether did you need only check sum value ?

Comment: try CHECKSUMFIXED=$( echo "$CHECKSUM"|sed 's/\s.*$//' )

Answer (score 0):

```
CHECKSUM=$(cksum $FILE|awk '{print $1}')
```

this gives you the first part. I hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Or simply:

```
read CHECKSUM __ < <(cksum "$FILE")
```

Also another way to do it with sed is

```
CHECKSUM=$(cksum "$FILE" | sed -e 's/[[:space:]]\+.*$//')
```